# What is the CSS for "width: whatever-is-left-in-the-line;"?

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to tell an HTML entity to take up all of the unused space in the line.  So, I would have something like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| normal text |    as much as possible    | some longer normal text    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is that I don't know the size of "normal" or "longer normal", so I can't set pixels, points, or percentages.  The best I know how to do is:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" with="100%">
<tr><td style="border: 1px solid red;">normal&nbsp;text</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid green; width: 100%;">as much as possible</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid red;">much&nbsp;longer;&nbsp;normal&nbsp;text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This seems really kludgy.  Not to mention that you need remember to use `&nbsp;` otherwise, the table will put line-breaks in-between your words.

In something like Qt, I would just set the expand property, or the stretchiness.  Is there any way to do this with CSS?

Edit:  Preferably without using tables

Comment: Does `white-space:nowrap;` not remove the need for `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP:  quite possibly.  However, I'd really prefer something without a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little known but amazingly effective technique for solving this exact problem:

```
Text-align: justify;
```

Basically it forces your divs to float to the left and to the right and take up as much space as they need, without having to use floats which have all sorts of other issues associated with them.

The interesting part of this is the added pseudo element. `Text-align: justify` doesn't apply to the last line (in your case, there is only one line). So you add a false last line after the real content, that way your single line of content gets the effect.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/dmtintner/pen/juzgi)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Any length text here</div>
  <div class="text">My Right side text as long as i want</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
      text-align: justify;
      line-height: 0; // so that the invisible last line doesn't take up space
      &:after { // adds a false last line to the content so justify is applied
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
.text { display: inline-block; }
```

further reading: http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/

[scss mixins to handle this](http://www.hackingui.com/front-end/10-best-scss-utilities/)

Comment: Interesting.  I wish that you could just force 'justify' to always work, because I'm never going to remember that container CSS without looking it up, but definitely better than a table!

Comment: @prewett, agreed however the normal usage for text-align is for text, and if that was the default usage it really wouldn't be usable, spreading the last line of text out like that. However,just wrap your code in an SCSS mixin so that you don't have to remember it. Also more reusable this way ( see link )

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to try set your "normal" or "longer normal" by giving different widths and then the middle one would automatically have a space to adjust whatever-is-left-in-the-line

Like I've added width for the "normal" or "longer normal"

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
  <tr><td style="border: 1px solid red;width:80px;">normal text</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid green; ">as much as possible</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid red;width:160px;">much longer normal text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can further work with the property

```
min-width: 00px; /* give any amount of pixels*/
```

giving minimum width will prevent the given 'td' from breaking the text into two lines

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XGb5K/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Any cell that isn't a set size (relative (%) or absolute (say, in pixels)) will automatically expand to fill any extra space, assuming the table is wider than the total starting width of all cells. If you want one particular cell to be the "filler" cell, the other cells need a set width.

If you do not want the text in all cells to wrap, @SmokeyPHP's suggestion is correct: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text/#white-space

```
table td { 
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```